# Stopping Continuous Animation on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseenter

Hopefully a quick question/answer.
I have a few animations set on elements all doing pretty much the same thing but to different classes. However, when I mouseenter and mouseleave very quickly the animation will "bug" and play another "frame" (ie. play the animations from start to finish one more time even though there are only, for example, 3 instances of me moving my mouse in and out of the object).

Does anyone have any solutions as to how I could stop this from happening such as clearing the animation so that it doesn't keep occuring after the cursor has left the object?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.project").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).find("img").animate({width:'120%',height:'120%', left:'-20px',top:'-20px'},100)
$(this).find(".overlay-project1").animate({opacity: 0.9},"fast")
$(this).find(".overlay-project2").animate({opacity: 0.95},"fast")
$(this).find(".overlay-project3").animate({opacity: 0.95},"fast")
mouseenter.stop(true,true);
});
$("div.project").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).find("img").animate({width:'100%',height:'100%', left:'0px', top:'0px'},"fast")
$(this).find(".featured").animate({opacity:1},200)
$(this).find(".overlay-project1").animate({opacity: 0},"fast")
$(this).find(".overlay-project2").animate({opacity: 0},"fast")
$(this).find(".overlay-project3").animate({opacity: 0},"fast")
mouseleave.stop(true,true);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(this).find(".overlay-project1").stop().animate({opacity: 0},"fast")
```

Comment: Great! Thanks very much. I kept finding comments about .stop() but I'm still learning the syntax so was unsure where it needed to go :)